# Inserting a constant array in between every other column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, insert

Let's say, I have an `M x N` matrix. Now, I want to insert a constant `M x 1` column vector (say all 1's) in between each of the `N` columns. Therefore, my resulting matrix would be of dimension (`M x (2*N-1)`), with every other column being 1's.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind creating a temporary matrix, one way to do it would be to do the following:

```
old_matrix = rand(M,N); % Just for example
new_matrix = ones(M,2*N-1);
new_matrix(:,1:2:end) = old_matrix;
```

Note that for an arbitrary constant matrix, you could replace the second line with the following:

```
new_matrix = repmat(const_array,1,2*N-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vertically concatenate a matrix of ones, reshape, and cut off the last column of ones.  For a matrix `A`:

```
B = reshape([A; ones(size(A))],size(A,1),[]);
B(:,end)=[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it, using the possibility of out of bounds indexing in assignments:

```
M(:,1:2:end*2)=M;
M(:,2:2:end)=1
```